# Apply .classList.add() to all divs that .startsWith("example") - No jQuery

Tags: javascript

I wish to do the following but am unsure on how to properly utilize the content targeted within `.startsWith`.

This is what I have:

```
var divClass = document.querySelector('div').getAttribute('class');

if (divClass.startsWith('example')){
  divClass.classList.add('width', 'height');
 }
```

as shown above, I have attempted to use `classList.add()` on `divClass` with no prevail. I believe this strategy is indeed incorrect, however, I believe something like the following is closer...

```
var divClass = document.querySelector('div').getAttribute('class');

if (divClass.startsWith("example")){
  example.classList.add('width', 'height');
 }
```

...Although I struggle to directly target **example** and use `.classList.add()` to apply classes to all divs with the **example** class.

If anyone has a solution to this It'd be greatly appreciated and I thank you in advance!

*FYI - All solutions please be in Vanilla JavaScript (No jQuery)*

Comment: does the 'example' class have to be the first ? classList is functionally an unordered set, actually. Only the order in the stylesheet affects what happens to the element, not the order of class names in its class attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this selector **getElementsByClassName**

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
        for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        list[i].classList.add("mystyle");
        }
```

for searching similar classes this solution works

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll('div');    
 var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if(x[i].classList.value.indexOf('example') > -1){
      x[i].classList.add("mystyle");
      }
    }
```

Comment: This works, however I wish to make it so that if I have a class called example-2, I can add to its class list by only targeting the 'example' part excluding the -2.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve all the div with the classname starting with `example` and iterate over the node collection you've found

```
let divClass = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="example"]');
[].forEach.call(divClass, function(div) {
  /* do something on div */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector` only gets one element, so you are only selecting the first `div` on the page and working with that. To get a list of elements, use `querySelectorAll`.

In jQuery you're able to call `$('div').addClass('example')` and you don't have to care whether there is one `div` or a lot, because jQuery handles looping through all of them for you. Without jQuery you have to do the iteration yourself:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
for ( var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ) {
    divs[ i ].classList.add('example')  
}
```

Or

```
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => div.classList.add('example'))
```

`document.querySelectorAll( selector )` is very similar to `$( selector )`, but `document.querySelector( selector )` is more like `$( selector ).first()`.